# Problem with running brew services list command

Tags: homebrew

I used homebrew and installed 'mongodb' and other services with it and I used `brew services list` to see my services and other brew commands to start and stop or restart them but today I could do any commands when I run `brew services list` it gives me this
`Warning: No services available to control with 'brew services'`
I know what this says but I used this before and I face this problem today I couldn't find out why?
I tried using `brew update --force` but it didn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: none of your Homebrew-installed packages expose services.

---

Longer answer, specifically for MongoDB: MongoDB has been [removed from Homebrew core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43770) due to its license. You can install MongoDB with Homebrew using [the MongoDB Homebrew tap](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew):

```
$ brew tap mongodb/brew
$ brew install mongodb-community
$ brew services start mongodb-community
```

Note that Homebrew removing the formula doesn't seem to stop the old `mongod` daemon (although it does remove it from the `brew services list`, so you can't `brew services stop` it), so if the service had previously been running you'll need to stop it (e.g. using `ps -x | grep mongo` followed by `kill <pid>`) *then* start the new service.

Comment: it works, but what happened to old mongo? it is running yet

Comment: What happened to the other services I used to manage with homebrew? @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you mean *"what happened"*? As I said, it got removed from core, so will have been removed from your machine at some subsequent Homebrew run. As to the other services, I don't know what they were.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you said I wonder how mongo is still running? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @RasoulSalehi it looks like Homebrew doesn't actually stop the old daemon when it removes the formula - you'll need to kill the daemon then restart the new version from `brew services`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you tell me how I can do that? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @RasoulSalehi I've added one way into the question; you need to find and stop `mongod`, *then* `brew services start mongodb-community`.